# Delay between stages in Bamboo

Tags: bamboo

I'm using bamboo to automate performance tests that should be run every night. I implemented two tests: first that run big queries and second that checks performance results.

First test (running queries) should be executed and after two hours second one (checking performance results) should be run. Obviously I don't want compile these tests into one test that run queries, waits 2 hours and checks results.

My solution is to have two bamboo plans: first plan with running queries test scheduled for 1:00 AM and second plan with checking performance results test scheduled for 3:00 AM. That works.

Is it possible to execute those tests within one bamboo plan (for example by setting two stages (with one test each) and setting delay between stages execution)?

**Edit:**

I have working solution that doesn't block agent for delay time (two scheduled plans). It works. I'm just wondering if it's possible to achieve same effect within one plan - sounds like functionality that could be available in Bamboo.

Answer (score -1):

If blocking the build agent for 2 hours is not an issue, you may add a script task at the end of the first stage, so that it waits for 2 hours until the next stage is started.

`sleep 2h`

You may also define your result plan as a child plan (in Dependencies tab) and then introduce a sleep time using script task at the end of the first plan. 
This way, your first plan will finish executing after 2 hours followed by the child plan.

Update: If your plan A is connected to a repository and is triggered when there is a new commit, you may connect the same repository in plan B and [introduce a quiet period](https://www.atlassian.com/continuous-delivery/understanding-the-quiet-period) that will wait for 2 hours before it executes. This way, your agent is not blocked for 2 hours.

Comment: I don't want to block agent for 2 hours (that's why I don't want to compile plans in to one with waiting 2h between). The thing is how to achieve delay without blocking agent.

Comment: If your plan is connected to a repository, you may Enable Quiet Period. This way, you may specify a delay after a single commit is detected before the build is started.

Comment: Nice, that will solve my another problem (commit triggers two plans that shouldn't be run in parrarel). Solution that I have now (two plans scheduled for 1:00 and 3:00) works. I'm looking for solution with one plan.

Comment: Please see my question edit for additional clarification.

Comment: An agent will be freed only after the whole plan is executed. Stages cannot be separated.(hope this gets an upvote) ;)

Comment: Agent is assigned to job (job cannot be processed by two agents), but 2 jobs in one stage can be processed parrarel by 2 agents. Therefore particular agent can be released after his job is executed. If we have stage1 with job1 and stage2 with job2 then stages can be executed by two agents.